# ERROR: The connection is in autoCommit mode

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

what's wrong with my code? I'm using mysql connector to work with mysql database. everything seems cool in build phase but when I run my code I get this error :

```
ERROR: SQLException in /programs/Mysql/main.cpp (main) on line 24
ERROR: The connection is in autoCommit mode (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState: )
```

this is my complete code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main(void) {
    try {
        Driver *driver;
        Connection *con;

        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "123");
        con->setAutoCommit(0);
        con->setSchema("webscope");
        delete con;
    } catch (SQLException &e) {
        cout << "ERROR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;

        if (e.getErrorCode() == 1047) {
            /*
            Error: 1047 SQLSTATE: 08S01 (ER_UNKNOWN_COM_ERROR)
            Message: Unknown command
            */
            cout << "\nYour server does not seem to support Prepared Statements at all. ";
            cout << "Perhaps MYSQL < 4.1?" << endl;
        }

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: I have removed some comments to get shorter code snippet.

Comment: sorry for bumping in, have you ever solved this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I actually ran into this issue as a result of including the wrong header files in my project's Makefile.**

In my Makefile, I was including headers for a Solaris release of MySQL, but was compiling on Linux. After pointing the includes to the correct MySQL release headers, I didn't get this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

"The connection is in autoCommit mode" so you can't start a transaction.

So find the method to set autoCommit to false.

autoCommit mode is the default mode for mySql at it means that each statement is its own transaction.

Comment: Odd. Also you should only get that exception if you begin a new transaction and your code here don't do that. Are you sure this is the only code you are running?

Comment: yes. I use this simple code to test running query on mysql. but I got this error. why I can not set  auto commit to false?